# Help needed in understanding an argument in Theorem 2.47 of topology by Wayne Patty

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

I am self studying topology from Wayne Patty and I have a question in Theorem 2.48 on page 90. Subsection is Weak topology and product topology.

[image]

> The question is that I am not able to understand how $\mathscr B$ is countable in 4th and 5th line of the proof. It is clear to me that for all $\alpha \in \Lambda- \Gamma$, $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1} (B_{\alpha}) =X$. But still I am not able to deduce how $\mathscr B$ is countable.

Please help me with that!

Comment: $\mathcal{B}$ is a countable product of countable sets $\mathcal{B}_\alpha$, so it remains countable. As cardinality goes, it's like $\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\omega\times\prod_{\alpha\notin\Gamma}\{1\}$.

Comment: @Chrystomath: That Cartesian product is uncountable. Fortunately, $\mathscr{B}$ is not the product of infinitely many countably infinite sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(You may already have realized this, but note that there is a typo in the fourth line: it should read ‘where $\alpha\in\Lambda$ and $B_\alpha\in\mathscr{B}_\alpha$’.)

For each $\alpha\in\Lambda$ let

$$\mathscr{S}_\alpha=\left\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}[B]:B\in\mathscr{B}_\alpha\right\}\,,$$

and let

$$\mathscr{S}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\mathscr{S}_\alpha\,.$$

If $\alpha\in\Lambda\setminus\Gamma$, then $\mathscr{B}_\alpha=\{X_\alpha\}$, so $\mathscr{S}_\alpha=\left\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}[X_\alpha]\right\}=\{X\}$. If $\alpha\in\Gamma$, then $\mathscr{B}_\alpha$ is countable, so $\mathscr{S}_\alpha$ is also countable. Thus,

$$\mathscr{S}=\{X\}\cup\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Gamma}\mathscr{S}_\alpha$$

is the union of countably many countable sets and is therefore countable. Finally, Patty’s $\mathscr{B}$ is the set of all intersections of finite subsets of $\mathscr{S}$. $\mathscr{S}$, being countable, has only countably many finite subsets, so $\mathscr{B}$ is also countable.

Comment: Why If $\alpha \in\Gamma $,then how does countability of $\mathscr{B}_\alpha \$ implies countability of $\mathscr{S}_\alpha$? I am not able to understand it

Comment: @Avenger: The map $$\mathscr{B}_\alpha\to\mathscr{S}_\alpha:B\mapsto\pi_\alpha^{-1}[B]$$ is a surjection, so $|\mathscr{B}_\alpha|\ge|\mathscr{S}_\alpha|$. If $\alpha\in\Gamma$, then $\mathscr{B}_\alpha$ is countable, and $|\mathscr{B}_\alpha|\ge|\mathscr{S}_\alpha|$, so $\mathscr{S}_\alpha$ must also be countable.